# xepersian's error: mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadab

Tags: fonts, xepersian

I use `xpersian` package to produce farsi document in ubuntu 12.04

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=0.9]{Junicode}
\begin{document}
سلام
\end{document}
```

but unfortunately, I get this error

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1enc.def
File: eu1enc.def 2008/03/08 v0.1d Experimental unicode font encoding
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 100.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd
File: eu1lmr.fd 2007/01/14 v1.3 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! Font EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadab
le: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
```

I changed the font to `Tahoma` but nothing else happened. Thaks to Herbert, this is my file list, which is different from his.

```
 *File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
xepersian.sty    2009/08/09 v1.0.3 <revision 93> Persian typesetting in LeLaTeX
bidi.sty    2009/08/09 v1.0.3 <revision 82> Bidirectional typesetting in Xe LaTeX
amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
footnote-bidi.def
article-bidi.def
fontspec.sty    2008/08/09 v1.18 Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX
ifxetex.sty    2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
fontenc.sty
eu1enc.def    2008/03/08 v0.1d Experimental unicode font encoding
eu1lmr.fd    2007/01/14 v1.3 Font defs for Latin Modern
fontspec.cfg
xepersian-persiancal.sty    
xepersian-mathsdigitspec.sty    2009/04/22 v1.0.1 Unicode Persian maths digits 
in XeLaTeX (Author: Vafa Khalighi)
etoolbox.sty    2009/08/06 v1.8 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
footnote-bidi-xepersian.def
article-xepersian.def
 ***********
```

every suggestion whould be appreciated.

Comment: Does a document with only `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{fontspec}` in it, followed by `\begin{document}Hello\end{document}` compile with XeLaTeX?

Comment: @egreg: I compiled it by `Texmaker` and in `Configure Texmaker>Quick Build` command is written `xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex %.aux|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|xdvi %.dvi`

Comment: Was there an error?

Comment: No! as the same of above error was happened

Comment: I changed it to `xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex %.aux|xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|xdvi %.dvi` and again the above error appeared!

Comment: @egreg: sorry! My last answer was about my document! I followed your advise and compile `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\begin{document}Hello\end{document}`, which I get `! Font EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadab`.

Comment: From the last comment we can deduce that you have a faulty installation.

Comment: I removed Tex Live by Ubuntu Software center and start to install it independent: http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

no problem here with current TL2012. Compare with the following file list which is available at the end of the file when you put `\listfiles` into your preamble:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
xepersian.sty    2012/12/12 v12 (Final Version) Persian typesetting in XeLaTeX
fontspec.sty    2012/05/06 v2.2b Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2012/11/21 v4332 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/09/24 v4230 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2012/07/16 v3991 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty    2012/11/10 v4306 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2012/08/28 v4149 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2012/09/28 v4244 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2012/09/26 v4237 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2012/11/01 v4251 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2012/11/04 v4260 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2012/11/02 v4256 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2012/11/10 v4305 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2012/11/04 v4259 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2012/11/09 v4298 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  xparse.sty    2012/11/21 v4332 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2012/05/06 v2.2b Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/Lu
aLaTeX
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2012/05/06 v2.2b Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaL
aTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg
xepersian-persiancal.sty    2012/07/25 v0.2 provides Persian calendar
xepersian-mathsdigitspec.sty    2012/01/01 v1.0.2 Unicode Persian maths digits 
in XeLaTeX
    bidi.sty    2012/12/12 v12 (Final Version) Bidirectional typesetting in pla
in TeX and LaTeX
   iftex.sty    2010/07/25 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
biditools.sty    2012/05/01 v0.1 Programming tools for bidi package
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
xetex-bidi.def    2012/12/12 v1.0.6 bidi adaptations for XeTeX engine
footnote-xetex-bidi.def    2012/12/12 v0.6 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engin
e
article-xetex-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.4 bidi adaptations for standard article
 class for XeTeX engine
graphicx-xetex-bidi.def    2012/01/01 v0.4 bidi adaptations for graphicx packag
e for XeTeX engine
loadingorder-bidi.def    2012/12/12 v0.9 making sure that bidi is the last pack
age loaded
loadingorder-bidi-xepersian.def    2012/01/01 v0.3 making sure that xepersian i
s the last package loaded
footnote-bidi-xepersian.def    2010/07/25 v0.2 footnote macros for xepersian pa
ckage
article-xepersian.def    2010/07/25 v0.2 adaptations for standard article class

localise-xepersian.def    2010/07/25 v0.2a Persian localisation of LaTeX2e
commands-ltx.def    2010/07/25 v0.2 Persian localisation of LaTeX2e commands
commands-xepersian.def    2012/07/25 v0.2 Persian localisation of XePersian com
mands
environments-ltx.def    2010/07/25 v0.2 Persian localisation of LaTeX2e environ
ments
environments-xepersian.def    2010/07/25 v0.1 Persian localisation of XePersian
 and bidi environments
messages-localise.def    2011/03/01 v0.1 localising LaTeX2e messages
misc-localise-xepersian.def    2012/01/01 v0.2 miscellaneous Persian localisati
on of LaTeX2e
packages-localise-xepersian.def    2011/03/01 v0.1 localising LaTeX2e Packages
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
 ***********
```

Comment: Thanks. but my file list is different!

Comment: @user98504: you have really old files ... you should update your system

Comment: @ Herbert: I just installed whole of the TeX Live last week by Ubuntu Software center!

Comment: Ubuntu updates TeXLive once per year. The TL from tug.org is updated daily!